# How to change Vi editor background

Tags: windows, linux, vim, putty

I am connecting through putty and i am using vim editor in putty and writing program  in perl. I dont have any particular vimrc file.

My problem is that in vim comments are rendered in DARK BLUE on BLACK BACKGROUND.

How to change that comments into some light color in vim or change some settings in putty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can either

- play around with

```
:set background=dark
:set background=light
```

- or use another colorscheme:

```
:colorscheme tab
```

- or change the coloring for a 'comment' in your current colorscheme with

```
:highlight Comment
```

(this shows you the current settings,  change it via

```
:highlight Comment guibg=white
```

or to whatever color you want.

Comment: How can I save these settings?

Comment: @Dean: store them in your .vimrc, read more about it http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html

Answer (score 4):

You can say the following in vim:

```
:set background=dark
```

This will set the syntax highlighting to bright colours. The opposite will set it to dark colours:

```
:set background=light
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of (or in addition to) changing the colors in vim (as suggested in the other answers), you can also configure PuTTY to use colors that are easier to distinguish. PuTTY's color settings are under "Window/Colours". You probably want to change "ANSI blue" and "ANSI blue bold" to be lighter/brighter.

The advantage is that this will affect display in all programs that use color (such as `ls --color` or `grep --color`) and for all systems you log into.

Answer (score 1):

See `/usr/share/vim/vim61/colors/README.txt` where `/usr/share/vim/vim61/` is your vim directory. `/usr/share/vim/vim61/colors/` holds all themes and configures the highlighting colors used.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to edit the c.vim / cpp.vim file
There is a variety of statement like:

```
  hi Comment       gui=NONE guifg=#0000ff
```

just change #0000ff to e.g. #999999 (a slightly dark gray)